# How to make the specified nodes horizontally aligned in Mermaid?

Tags: flowchart, mermaid

This is my flowchart:

```
graph TB
    aaa ---> bbb ---> ddd & ccc
    ddd -.-> fff
    ccc --->|eee| fff
    fff ---> hhh & ggg & kkk
    hhh --->|iii| mmm
    ggg & kkk -.-> mmm
```

[image]

But actually I want the node `ccc` and node `ddd` to be aligned horizontally. And the `hhh` , node `ggg` and `kkk` to be aligned horizontally. Is it possible?

---

Of course, the purpose of this post is to think about how to align these nodes horizontally, but if possible I would also like to make these edges as short as possible to save space while aligning them. For example, I want the node `ddd` to go up, not the node `ccc` to come down

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can achieve this by [using longer or shorter arrows](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=minimum-length-of-a-link), which changes the minimum link length between nodes:

```
graph TB
    aaa ---> bbb ---> ddd & ccc
    ddd -..-> fff
    %%   ^^ extra .
    ccc --->|eee| fff
    fff ---> hhh & ggg & kkk
    hhh --->|iii| mmm
    ggg & kkk -..-> mmm
    %%         ^^ extra .
```

[image: Flowchart with nodes aligned as OP wishes]

Answer (score 4):

According [Minimum length of a link](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=minimum-length-of-a-link) <sup>[permalink](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/blob/1509ee68bede6c6dc12bcc196d54b89f3b97ac4a/docs/flowchart.md?plain=1#L278-L296)</sup>

> Each node in the flowchart is ultimately assigned to a rank in the rendered graph, i.e. to a vertical or horizontal level (depending on the flowchart orientation), based on the nodes to which it is linked. By default, links can span any number of ranks, **but you can ask for any link to be longer than the others by adding "extra dashes" in the link definition.**

so you don't need to triple dash

change

- `C2 ---> |msg| D` to `C2 --> |msg| D`
- `E1 --->|msg| F`  to `E1 -->|msg| F`

### Compare

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/8.14.0/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
  <th>Bad</th>
  <th>Good</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="mermaid">
      graph TB
      A --> B --> C1 & C2
      C1 -.-> D
      C2 ---> |msg| D
      D --> E1 & E2 & E3
      E1 --->|msg| F
      E2 & E3 -.-> F
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="mermaid">
      graph TB
      A --> B --> C1 & C2
      C1 -.-> D
      C2 --> |msg| D
      D --> E1 & E2 & E3
      E1 -->|msg| F
      E2 & E3 -.-> F
    </div>
  </td>  
</tr>
</table>
```