# horizontally align specific nodes in mermaid graph

Tags: javascript, html, mermaid

I have a large mermaid graph. I wanted to print some of the sections vertically rather than horizontally.

I was able to shift some of the groups of the graph downward by adding dashes to the arrows in the mermaid graph code:  `---->` instead of `-->`.

Here is a minimial example which shows what I am talking about:

```
<html lang="en" style="height: auto;">
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mermaid">
    graph TD;
    A-->B;
    B-->C;
    C-->D;
    C------>E;
    C-------->F;
    C---------->G;
    
    D-->d1;
    D-->d2;
    D-->d3;
    D-->d4;
    
    d2-->dd1;
    d2-->dd2;
    d2-->dd3;
    
    E-->e1;
    E-->e2;
    E-->e3;
    E-->e4;
    
    F-->f1;
    F-->f2;
    F-->f3;
    F-->f4;
    
    G-->g1;
    G-->g2;
    G-->g3;
    G-->g4;
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/8.13.4/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfkit@0.10.0/js/pdfkit.standalone.js"></script>
<script src="https://bundle.run/blob-stream@0.1.3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg-to-pdfkit@0.1.8/source.js"></script>

<script>
mermaid.init({
    flowchart: { useMaxWidth: false },
    "theme": "default",
    "themeVariables": {
        "fontFamily": "Helvetica"
    }
}, document.querySelectorAll(".mermaid"));
</script>
```

The above code produces this image:

[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/8.14.0/mermaid.min.js"></script>
<div class="mermaid">
  graph TD;
    A-->B;
    B-->C;
    C-->D;
    C------>E;
    C-------->F;
    C---------->G;
    
    D-->d1;
    D-->d2;
    D-->d3;
    D-->d4;
    
    d2-->dd1;
    d2-->dd2;
    d2-->dd3;
    
    E-->e1;
    E-->e2;
    E-->e3;
    E-->e4;
    
    F-->f1;
    F-->f2;
    F-->f3;
    F-->f4;
    
    G-->g1;
    G-->g2;
    G-->g3;
    G-->g4;
</div>
```

But there is a lot of wasted space here. I want each section to be vertically below the previous section. Where by sections I mean nodes C, D, E, F, and G. To clarify, I would like nodes C, D, E, F, and G, to have the same horizontal coordinates, and to accomplish that, each should have a lower vertical coordinate.

At the moment node F is placed horizontally after node E's last child, e4. I would like node E to be horizontally the same position as node D, just below all of node E's children.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Note: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71096213/2300622) answer with a similar title, but the answer does not work on the graph in this example. The answer does not align the nodes horizontally it just shifts things down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line of markdown to:

```
graph LR;
```

This stands for 'left-to-right' whereas TD stands for 'top-down'. Now the chart looks like this:

[image: A left to right graph]

Comment: Giving you answer by default since the question is so old I can't even remember writing it